# regex for pattern between comma and period

Tags: r, regex, stringr

After hours of googling and fruitless attempts, I'm hoping someone can help with this admittedly easy question (although regexps are fairly unfamiliar to me evidently).

I have the following type of data:

```
name <- c("Doe, Mr. John")
```

and I want "Mr" from this, but the actual title varies. My main question is how I write regular expression in order to capture just the "Mr" part, without anything else?

My current approach is as follows:

```
library(stringr)
str_split(name, "[,\\s.]")[[1]][[3]]
```

and the best I managed to do using extraction was this:

```
str_extract(name, ", .*\\.")
```

I'm sure there's a simpler way, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may match all letters before a dot:

```
> name <- c("Doe, Mr. John")
> str_extract(name, "\\p{L}+(?=\\.)")
[1] "Mr"
```

Where `\\p{L}+` matches 1 or more letters and `(?=\\.)` is a positive lookahead requiring a dot right after them.

The same can be done with base R `regmatches` / `regexpr` using a PCRE regex (by passing a `perl=TRUE` argument to `regexpr`):

```
> regmatches(name, regexpr("\\p{L}+(?=\\.)", name, perl=TRUE))
[1] "Mr"
```

A similar regex can be be used with a `str_match` to ensure we only match the word after a comma, whitespaces and right before a dot:

```
> str_match(name, ",\\s*(\\p{L}+)\\.")[,2]
[1] "Mr"
```

Comment: This looks very nice! Thanks a lot. A quick but related question: how do I force ", " to be one "character" (group?)? For example, when I used the str_split function, my original intention was to split the string at ", " (i.e. including space) and also at ". ". But the way I wrote it it was interpreted as "split at comma, dot and whitespace".

Comment: Perhaps, you mean you actually wanted `str_split(name, "[,.]\\s*")[[1]][2]`? A character class `[,.]` matches either a `,` or a `.` at the current position.

Comment: BTW, `\p{L}` can be replaced with a `[[:alpha:]]`. If you only need to support ASCII letters, instead of `\p{L}`, you may use a common `[A-Za-z]` character class.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
sub("^[^ ]+\\s+([^.]+)\\..*", '\\1', name)
#[1] "Mr"
```